# Why are all the tabs not showing in Material UI tab component in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

### What I am creating?

- I am creating a horizontally scrollable tab component for selecting date of a month
- I am using the [Material UI library](https://mui.com/base/react-tabs/)

### Problem

- The dates before `14th Sun` is not showing in the site. (as shown in the image below)
- The first tab should be the 1st day of the month. Instead it is `14th Sun`
- In the browser elements tab, all the tabs are there. But they are not appearing on the screen

### Mobile Viewport (cannot scroll before 14th; starts there)

[image: mobile viewport]

### Desktops Viewport (cannot scroll before 7th)

[image: desktop viewport]

### Elements tab

[image: Elements tab]

Part of the code i think is the problem

```
export default function DayScrollView() {
  const [activeDate, setActiveDate] = useContext(dateContext)
  const [dates, setDates] = useState(getDatesInMonth(activeDate))
  return (
    <Box sx={
      {
        overflowX: 'scroll',
        scrollbarWidth: 'none',
        '-ms-overflow-style': 'none',
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
          display: 'none',
        },
      }
    }>
      <Tabs defaultValue={0}>
        <StyledTabsList>
          {dates.map((date, index) => {
            console.log(`${date.getDate()} ${date.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'short' })}`)
            return (
              <StyledTab key={date.toDateString()} value={date.toDateString()} onClick={() => setActiveDate(date)}>
                <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{date.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'short' })}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='h5'>{date.getDate()}</Typography>
              </StyledTab>
            )
          })}
        </StyledTabsList>
      </Tabs>
      <Box mr={10} sx={{ width: 20 }} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

### Whole Component Code

```js
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import Tabs from '@mui/base/Tabs';
import TabsList from '@mui/base/TabsList';
import TabPanel from '@mui/base/TabPanel';
import { buttonClasses } from '@mui/base/Button';
import Tab, { tabClasses } from '@mui/base/Tab';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import getDatesInMonth from '@/utils/getDatesInMonth';
import { dateContext } from '@/pages/mob';

export default function DayScrollView() {
  const [activeDate, setActiveDate] = useContext(dateContext)
  const [dates, setDates] = useState(getDatesInMonth(activeDate))
  return (
    <Box sx={
      {
        overflowX: 'scroll',
        scrollbarWidth: 'none',
        '-ms-overflow-style': 'none',
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
          display: 'none',
        },
      }
    }>
      <Tabs defaultValue={0}>
        <StyledTabsList>
          {dates.map((date, index) => {
            console.log(date)
            return (
              <StyledTab key={index} value={index} onClick={() => setActiveDate(date)}>
                <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{date.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'short' })}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='h5'>{date.getDate()}</Typography>
              </StyledTab>
            )
          })}
        </StyledTabsList>
      </Tabs>
      <Box mr={10} sx={{ width: 20 }} />
    </Box>
  );
}

const StyledTab = styled(Tab)`
.... some css styles
`;

const StyledTabPanel = styled(TabPanel)(
  ({ theme }) => `
  width: 100%;
  ... more styles
  `,
);

const StyledTabsList = styled(TabsList)(
  ({ theme }) => `
  padding-right: 1rem;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
`,
);
```

### getDatesInMonth()

```js
function getDatesInMonth(date) {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth();
    const numDays = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
    const dates = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
        dates.push(new Date(year, month, i));
    }
    return dates;
}
```

- If any more information needed, write in the comments.
- Upvote and share the Question if you know someone who can help

Comment: When you log the dates inside the StyledTabsList, is it logging all of them including the dates before 14?

Comment: The styledTab styles would be useful here — could you share those? Also, have you tried setting the key to something other than index (e.g., the stringified date)?

Comment: @ionosphere In the browser console, all the dates are logged in ascending order, from 1st to 31st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a css flex-box issue.

Try the following:

```
const StyledTabsList = styled(TabsList)(
  ({ theme }) => `
  padding-right: 1rem;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
  `,
);
```

Changed:

- changed justify-content: center to justify-content: flex-start;